# Capacitor notation number multiplied by number in circuit diagram (22x16)

Tags: capacitor

[image]On circuit diagrams, I sometimes see the notations for the capacitors like C57, 22x16, or C40, 10x10

What is 22x16 (10x10)? (it's not the physical dimensions).

Comment: When you say "It is not the size", do you mean the physical dimensions (mm)?

Comment: Please show a picture as example.

Comment: Possibly capacitance value and rated voltage.

Comment: @HandyHowie, yes, not physical dimensions

Comment: @Huisman, just a sec, i'll add

Comment: @PeterSmith, thanks, I also thought so, but just wanted to double check. The first goes the capacitance, then the voltage. is it so?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> What is 22x16 (10x10)? (it's not the size).

In this case, it is (as suggested by *Peter Smith* in a comment): capacitance value "x" rated voltage

For example, see [this example](http://www.rodaronline.com/productos/ver/1331/Cap-Radial-16V-22uf-105) on Rodar Electronica's website of "22x16" (see green boxes):

---

[image: sales page of 22uF 16V capacitor showing 22x16 in the part number]

---

And here is another random example, this time a listing from [this website](https://lista.mercadolivre.com.br/capacitor-4%2C7x100), describing a capacitor of 47uF 100V as "47x100":

---

[image: capacitor sales listing for 47uF 100V described as 47x100]

---

In my experience, this notation seems to be used more in some parts of the world than others.

However **beware**, because *sometimes* that notation of "number x number" *can* refer to the capacitor's size. Here is [an example](https://www.tme.eu/en/details/ce-1000_25pht-j/105degc-tht-electrolytic-capacitors/jamicon/tkr-1000uf-25v-10x16/) where "10x16" in the description means a diameter of 10mm and 16mm tall and does *not* refer to the capacitor value and rated voltage:

---

[image: capacitor listing where 10x16 refers to capacitor size not value and voltage rating]